# How to use Hive jobs with Azkaban?

Tags: hadoop, hive, azkaban

I would like to use Azkaban for periodic Hive jobs, I have looked through Azkaban documentation, and it seems like by default it doesn't support Hive jobs, do you know how can I use these two together?

I think, I'll have to run Hive jobs as a "command job" available in Azkaban, but maybe someone has worked it out.
I was using Oozie for some time, but It didn't meet my needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now we don't have an easy way.  You can certainly hack into the HiveCliDriver and do it from there, but it's suboptimal... Alternatively, just run it as a command line job. We're using a different system at LI.  I hope to add this ability pretty quickly, but not sure when I'll have the chance.

Comment: Any progress on Hive support now?

Comment: Can you give any pointers about the Hack that can be used to run HIVE jobs from Azkaban?

Comment: We did add this and it's being added as part of the Azkaban 2 roll out: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/azkaban-dev/Mc1_gpsQ7uw/discussion.  The actual Hive workflow type should hit the github within the next week or so.  If you're in Silicon Valley, Richard will be presenting on this work next week: http://www.meetup.com/Open-Data-Bay-Area/events/105644322/?a=co1.3_grp&rv=co1.3  Otherwise, keep an eye on the public list.

Answer (score 1):

As of Azkaban 2.1, Hive jobs are supported. For details, see the [documentation](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban2/documents/2.1/jobtypes.html).